# Django JsonResponse returning content-type text/html instead of application/json

Tags: python, json, django, travis-ci, jsonresponse

I've hit a dead end with a django web-project I'm working on and I can't seem to find any answers.
I'm trying to test a view as simple as this:

```
def list(request):
    return JsonResponse( {"foo": "bar"} )
```

It seems to run all well. If I open the site on my browser and check the Page-Info it says "Type: application/json".

However, when I run following test on a travis ci:

```
def setUpTestData(cls):
    cls.client = Client()
    #A few lines of setting up test-data

def test_content_type(self):
    response = self.client.get('/api/list')
    self.assertEqual(response['content-type'], 'application/json')
```

I get following Failure:

```
FAIL: test_content_type (researchlibrary.api.tests.test_list.ListTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/travis/build/FUB-HCC/ACE-Research-Library/researchlibrary/api/tests/test_list.py", line 25, in test_content_type
    self.assertEqual(response['content-type'], 'application/json')
AssertionError: 'text/html' != 'application/json'
- text/html
+ application/json
```

The urls are all fine. The test recieves the correct page, just the type appears to be text/html instead of application/json and I have no clue why that is.

Anybody got any ideas as to why this could be?

EDIT: changing self.client.get('/api/list') to self.client.get('/api/list/') solved the problem.

Comment: I think you should check the content of the response. It's possible you are getting an error page instead of the usual response.

Comment: @LudwikTrammer You're right. Typing the adress `localhost/api/list` returns the correct response but somehow that doesnt seem to be the case with the test. I tried changing it to `self.client.get('/api/list/')` and that indeed did the job. Thanks :D I feel kind of stupid now ^^

Comment: @LudwikTrammer You should create that as an answer.

Comment: @cwallenpoole it was just a guess, and I wasn't even right, despite what OP claims ;) The reason was not an error page sent with a text/html, but an HTTP redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that

```
self.client.get('/api/list')
```

led to an error-page (hence the text/html content_type).

EDIT: Not an error-page, but an http-redirect, according to LudwikTrammer.

Changing

```
self.client.get('/api/list')
```

to

```
self.client.get('/api/list/')
```

solved the issue.